# LCD with RTC and GPS

Tags: gpio, display, peripherals, rtc

I have purchased [a LCD board](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1109), [a real time clock board](http://www.adafruit.com/products/264), and [a GPS board](http://www.adafruit.com/products/746).

I have soldered the LCD onto the breakout board as instructed and put the realtime clock together following the tutorials. At this point, I'd like to hook them up to my Raspberry PI and start writing code to use them together. It looks like they all use the GPIO pins which become inaccessible once the LCD is placed on top of the PI.

How do I go about using these items together or did I make a mistake in my hardware planning?

**Edit:** I forgot the GPS can be used via a USB port. My question only applies to the LCD and RTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need GPS and RTC?

Last time I checked, GPS provides very precise time, so you may easily ditch RTC from your setup. And everything falls right in place, LCD connected through GPIO pins and GPS to the USB port.

Comment: I did not know that. The description did not mention that fact so I guess it's just common knowledge. That simplified things quite a bit.

Comment: Using an RTC is a decent backup to allow the RPI to "fast-start" and have access to higher-stratum time before the GPS loads in.  I didn't add an RTC to my RPi time server, but I can see where one could be useful in an "internet outage AND i just replaced my GPS's battery" situation while you wait the 15-30 min for GPS to sync.

Answer (score -1):

. . You need both because when the gps is unavailable you need the RTC to keep you going . .

Comment: Depends entirely on the usecase. While the Pi is running it has no trouble keeping its clock running on its own.